# Can't create table and Insert data using SQLite in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio

I have made a class that's called DataBaseHelperFoodLogger that extends SQLiteOpenHelper, and whenever I call the addItem method, its supposed to create the table if it doesn't exist, and then insert the values that the user introduced (from the activity where the method is called), I even have a bit of code that gives me confirmation on whether the data was introduced or not, if it does it'll toast "Success = true" or false if it couldn't insert the data. It always gives me true, but then when I go to check the database using "DB Browser for SQLite", not only did it not insert anything, but the table that was created on the onCreate method doesn't exist.

The odd thing about it, is that I have another class that's basically identical but with its respective methods and table, and that seems to be working just fine.

### DataBaseHelperFoodLogger.java

```
public class DataBaseHelperFoodLogger extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public static final String FOOD_LOGGER_TABLE_NAME = "FOOD_LOGGER_TABLE_NAME";

        public static final String FOOD_LOGGER_DATE = "FOOD_LOGGER_DATE";
        public static final String FOOD_LOGGER_MEALTIME_ID = "FOOD_LOGGER_MEALTIME_ID";
        public static final String FOOD_LOGGER_ID = "FOOD_LOGGER_ID";
        public static final String FOOD_LOGGER_FOOD_ID = "FOOD_LOGGER_FOOD_ID";


        public DataBaseHelperFoodLogger(@Nullable Context context) {
            super(context, "food.db" , null, 1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + FOOD_LOGGER_TABLE_NAME + " (" + FOOD_LOGGER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + FOOD_LOGGER_MEALTIME_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " + FOOD_LOGGER_DATE + " VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, " + FOOD_LOGGER_FOOD_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL)";
            db.execSQL(createTable);


        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        }

        public boolean addItem (FoodItemEditable item, String date, int mealtimeID) {

            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

            cv.put(FOOD_LOGGER_DATE, date);
            cv.put(FOOD_LOGGER_MEALTIME_ID, mealtimeID);
            cv.put(FOOD_LOGGER_FOOD_ID, item.getFoodId());


            db.insert(FOOD_LOGGER_TABLE_NAME, null, cv);

            long insert = db.insert(FOOD_LOGGER_TABLE_NAME, null, cv);

            if (insert == -1) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }

        }
        


}
```

### dashboard_fragment.java (where I call the addItem method)

```
    if (intent != null) {
        item = (FoodItemEditable) intent.getSerializableExtra("agua");
        if (buttonMealtimeIndicator != 0) {
            DataBaseHelperFoodLogger db = new DataBaseHelperFoodLogger(getActivity());
            Boolean success = db.addItem(item, date, buttonMealtimeIndicator);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Success = " + success, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            addItemToList();

        }
    }
```

Comment: *...It always gives me true...* What do you expect to get with `return true;`?

Comment: Store the output of `insert`, which returns a `long` corresponding to the new row ID. Either log this result to aid debugging, or ensure `addItem` returns `false` if this figure is negative.

Comment: @forpas my mistake, forgot to ctrl+z on my code, it's not supposed to look like that, I'll edit the code

Comment: @codebod that's what I had originally, then I went to try some stuff to see if it fixes and I forgot to revert it back to that instead of just having "return true;"

Comment: If your code is as it is now and the method `addItem()` returns `true`, it means that the row was inserted successfully in the table.

Comment: @forpas that's what I logically thought too, but when I go to check, nope, nothing

Comment: @forpas aha!, I get what's wrong now, since I had the database open in the DB Browser, I couldn't replace the file with the updated database file since the original one was being used and open